# TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_bad_lines', on reading my csv

Tags: python, pandas

So i am trying to read out a csv, and i got this interesting error on the on_bad_lines parameter.
The idea was to read out my dataset and take off any weird line that has more fields than it should. On a very screwed up df of mine, but the thing is pandas is not even recognizing the parameter which is just weird. Does someone know why?

Here is a print screen of my notebook can someone explain to me why is this happening?
[image]

Comment: you probably have an older version of pandas. try upgrading to latest.

Comment: it seems your pandas version is 1.1.5, `on_bad_lines` was added in 1.3

Comment: Oh yeah, i was used to my sublime ide.  I forgot to patch up my conda env thank you guys